A movie starring only one person, who complains the whole way through
I'm trying to remember a movie I saw years ago. I think it came out originally in the late 80's/early 90's and it just stars one man pacing about his apartment and complaining.
I think he dies at the end.
I think this movie had a cameo by a young Jim Carrey (he plays the devil, but is only in the movie for a few seconds at the end), but I can't find anything like that on his IMDB page, can somebody remember?

Sounds like High Strung from 1991. You probably didn't find it because Jim Carrey went uncredited. From the recap:

The film centers around Thane Furrows, who spends the day messing around his apartment and complaining about a number of random subjects

Carrey plays Death, but he has little devil horns in the poster. The movie is available on Youtube.
